# How to avoid partial mocking or how to do full mocks using sinon?

Tags: javascript, mocking, tdd, sinon

As far as I know all mocks in SinonJS are partial mocks, witch lead to uncut dependencies in tests when doing TDD.

This is an example of testing a method that connects to database and performs an insert:

- Fist test: Mock connection to database to check params.
- Implement connection logic to pass test.
- Second test: Stub connection to database and mock insert to database.
- Implement insert logic to pass test.

Doing this the first test will do the insert logic.

I know that full instances can be stubbed, but once stubbed it cannot be mocked.

Is there any way to create a full mock or any alternative?